# Creating a back link using Grails

Tags: grails, gsp

I need to do "back" link in gsp page. How to realize it without using controllers and actions? For example via history-stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like a javascript question rather than gsp...

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:window.history.back();">Back</a>
```

If you were really using grails you could do something like this

Controller:

```
def prevLoc=request.getHeader('referer')
```

gsp:

```
<a href="# onclick="javascript:window.location.replace('${prevLoc}');">Back</a><
```

Comment: please note, that the referer is just some string sent (or not) from the browser (or anything in between). don't rely on it and don't enforce it, unless you know, what you are doing.